# ASP MVC: Can I drop a client connection programatically?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an ASP.NET Web API application running behind a load balancer. Some clients keep an HTTP busy connection alive for too much time, creating unnecessary affinity and causing high load on some server instances. In order to fix that, I wish to gracefully close a connection that is doing too much requests in a short period of time (thus forcing the client to reconnect and pick a different server instance) while at same time keeping low traffic connections alive indefinitely. Hence I cannot use a static configuration.

Is there some API that I can call to flag a request to "answer this then close the connection" ? Or can I simply add the `Connection: close` HTTP header that ASP.NET will see and close the connection for me?

Comment: I'm curious to know how you can tell the requests are coming from the same HTTP connection?

Comment: Good question. I hope that gets answered too!

Comment: @David you can certainly tell which IP address they are coming from, but potentially, if you have 100 users from the same company, then they are all the same IP address and you will drop them all.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the good solution for your situation will be the built-in IIS functionality called [Dynamic IP restriction](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-dynamic-ip-address-restrictions). "To provide this protection, the module temporarily blocks IP addresses of HTTP clients that make an unusually high number of concurrent requests or that make a large number of requests over small period of time."

It is supported by Azure Web Apps:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/confirming-dynamic-ip-address-restrictions-in-windows-azure-web-sites/

---

If that is the helpful answer, please mark it as a helpful or mark it as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks but doesn't work. This would block the IP address on that instance and return an error such as 401 or 403. I want to return a 200 and close the connection, forcing the client to reconnect.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I made some research and asked teammates if the did something like that, and i need to say that i did not find the ready-to-go solution. There is https://github.com/stefanprodan/WebApiThrottle which i think can be used partially in your situation and implement throttling logic resulting not in the blocking but in the returning what you want. Sorry for not being able to help :-(

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure this would work in your situation, but in the past I have had to block people coming from specific IP addresses geographically and people coming from common proxies. I created an Authorized Attribute class following:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters

In would dump the person out based on their IP address by returning a HttpStatusCode.BadRequest. On every request you would have to check a list of bad ips in the database and go from there. Maybe you can handle the rest client side, because they are going to get a ton of errors.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't care about the client IP address. I just want to prevent a client from pinning an instance in the server.

Answer (score 1):

Write an [action filter](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs) that returns a 302 Found response for the 'blocked' IP address.  I would hope, the client would close the current connection and try again on the new location (which could just be the same URL as the original request).

Comment: Thanks, but returning a 302 is a breaking change in REST interface. I want to just close the connection after sending the response, and only after a given number of requests coming from that connection (not IP address).

Comment: Why is returning a 302 a breaking change?  It should be transparent to the client.